# T-sql Like statement and trailing zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

Using SQL Server, imagine you have decimal stored as a nvarchar and you want to compare it to another nvarchar using 'like'. Assuming you provide the significant digits, this should be fine (albeit not ideal):

```
declare @test1 nvarchar(18);
declare @test2 nvarchar(18);

set @test1 = '1.15%';
set @test2 = '1.1500000000000000';

select 
    case when @test1 like @test2 then 'Yes' 
    else 'No' 
    end as result;
```

This returns the result of 'No', why is that the case?

EDIT: In response to the answers, ever have one of those days? Hah, thanks for the help.

Comment: "imagine you have decimal stored as a nvarchar" This statement means you are doing something wrong to begin with.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't control the schema of this particular database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `@test1` and `@test2` are the wrong way around in the `LIKE` statement...

```
select 
    case when @test2 like @test1 then 'Yes' 
    else 'No' 
    end as result;
```

Answer (score 3):

The right-hand operand to `LIKE` is not a string literal, but a pattern that can include `%` and `_` as wildcards. In your case, the right-hand operand is `@test2`, which does not include such wildcards, and so only matches strings that are identical to it.

If you invert the order, i.e. do `@test2 LIKE @test1`, you'll see the intended result.